# Loading Google Chart Api using Ajax in html page

Tags: html, ajax, google-visualization

I am using Ajax code to load the html page

for example:

```
  $.ajax({
  url: 'Context.html',
  dataType: 'html',
  timeout: 500, 
  success: function(html) {
  $("div#mainbody").html(html);
  }
  });
```

The Context.html I am loading it in some other html page say Home.html

But I am generating pie charts using google API in Context.html

and the code for generating pie chart i.e in Context.html is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Count'],
      ['2005',  70],
      ['2006',  80],
      ['2007',  140],
      ['2008',  220],
      ['2009',  290],
      ['2010',  400],
      ['2011',  500]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Head Count-(Apple Year)',
      colors:['#129212']              
      };
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('jsf_headcount_bargraph'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
```

When I am loading Context.html in Home.html page I cannot find the pie chart which is in Context.html after loading it in the Home.html

I tried  by giving ALERT(""); in script where I wrote code for pie chart. I was getting alert message,so Ajax is executing javascript but I am not getting pie chart which is same script. So I was stucked with Loading pie chart in Home.html page

Comment: Alternatives: Draw chart on same page and keep hidden till not required. OR You can use Image pie chart. Hope that will work.

Comment: I have the same problem.how to do it?

Comment: Is the only purpose of Context.html to draw a chart, or is there something else there?  Is the div "jsf_headcount_bargraph" in your main page or in context.html?

Answer (score 0):

If you make Context.html like this

```
<script>
var j = 20;
alert();
</script>
```

Then I do get an alert (using $.ajax({success: function() {} }) etc. ).

[ Example ]

```
function execAjax() {
    $.ajax( {
        url: 'index2.html',
        success: function( html ) {
            $("#content").html( html );

            checkJSvalue();
        },
        error: function() {
            alert( "Error" );
        }
    });
}

function checkJSvalue() {

    alert( j );
}
```

Example HTML (index2.html)

```
<div>
content of index2.html
</div>
<script>
var j = 20;
alert();
</script>
```

What I have tried to do is to put the code directly in the 'home.html' and I already got errors. You should reverse the order of usage and declaration of the drawchart function anyways.

```
// Bad
// google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
// function drawChart() {}

// Good
function drawChart() {}
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

Other than that, I already got this error from the google.jsapi.js (copied locally)

```
Uncaught Error: Container is not defined format+nl,default,corechart.I.js:841
```

So something goes wrong there, that is not part of the actual question and it's minified etc. so I won't go there.

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything works just fine if i replace the code

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

To inline

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart'], "callback": drawChart});
```